# MS Power-Automate ,Convert File(Preview) function to Convert Excel (with Link) to PDF (Link lost)

Tags: power-automate

Please Help me

I use Microsoft Automate for  convert **Excel file (on Cloud O365) with Link ** to **PDF File ( Can't Click Link) **(Convert File(Preview) Function)

Last December  , My pdf still can click Link , 
( between  I  edited  link in excel on cloud but i don't check it

This Month , my PDF can't click link Ready , I checked it wiht adobe acrobat , Chrome , Edge  ,  same problem

I checked my excel by download to desktop , the  link still can click on excel ............

How to edit Excel 0365 on Cloud  or edit Configurarion  in Convert File(Preview) Function

Comment: Too hard to help mate, no screenshots, etc. I personally have no idea what you’re talking about.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.